# Visual Studio Installer for WPF Application install gets stuck

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, installation, vsinstaller

I've created a VS Installer Setup for my WPF app (Visual C#, .NET), and I set the app to be launched at the end of the installation. It works so launching, but the installer gets stuck at the end.

You can see in the screenshot below that the app (the blurred part) has already been started, but the installer shows "Please wait..." and is stopped. And the installer will finish right then if I closed the app itself.

How can I set this to not get stuck? What could be wrong?

[image]

Comment: how did you sets your app to starts at the end, and post your app.xaml.cs code

Comment: Sounds like the call to start the app is a blocking call that only returns after your application is closed.